# Can a staggered DiD approach be valid in a setting of visual parallel trends but no clear treatment because of multiple different treatment points?

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am currently looking at the effect of the introduction of Carbon Tax/ETS on corporate investment behavior. I do have a cross-sectional panel-data from the period 2000-2022 and grouped the firms by industry and whether they are in a country that has introduced such a policy or not. I have found 5 industries where there are visually seem to be some kind of parallel trend. However, as the treatments have been placed at different points in time I cannot really identify a clear breaking point (and of course not considering differences in firms, countries visually) and in general thought about a staggered DiD in this case. Would such an approach be valid in this case to estimate the effect of the introduction of such a policy? I probably also need to make sure that the firm and countries are the same across industries.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome. So you’re sampling different sets of firms each year, by industry? Also, do you have similar start times *within industries*?

Comment: No I am sampling the same firms from 2000-2022. I group the firms by industry and then seperate them into treatment and control depending on whether they are in a country that introduced the treatment at some point or not. The treatment start times differ, so some firms in the treatment group received the treatment in 2005 others in 2010 e.g., depending on the country. So I basically want to compare whether companies adapt after the introduction of the policy by comparing it to firms in countries where it wasnt introduced. Industries make firms more comparable as I was looking for a trend.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So when does treatment start for firms in say, Industry 31?